# Rendering of local images in <v-carousel-item> not working but online image links are working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to vuejs and vuetify, I am trying to create a simple carousel component in a sample app created using the vue cli 3.
I am able to get the carousel content but its not loading the local images present in the asset folder, but the sample images in the vuetify page containing an online link of the image is working.

```
<template>
<div> 
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
     <v-img contain :src="items[i]"></v-img>
  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data() {
    items: [
        '../assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/2.PNG',
        '../assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/1.PNG',
        "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg",
        "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
      ]
  }
}
</script>
```

The images 1.PNG and 2.PNG is not working but the other two are.
Can someone help me on this, what I am missing.

Answer (score 12):

"Vue loader converts **relative paths** into require functions automatically for you. Unfortunately, this is not the case when it comes to custom components. You can circumvent this issue by using **require**. If you're using Vuetify as a Vue-CLI 3 plugin, you can edit your project's vue.config.js file by modifying the options for vue-loader." from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#relative-images-are-not-working-in-v-card-v-img-and-other-custom-vuetify-components)

```
// Incorrect
<v-img src="../path/to/img" />

 // Correct
 <v-img :src="require('../path/to/img')" />
```

So, I would change your `items` array to this format:

```
items: [
    {
      src: require('../assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/2.PNG')
    },
    {
      src: require('../assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/1.PNG')
    },
    {
      src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg'
    }
  ]
```

And your html like this:

```
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  ></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: you save my life dude!

Comment: I'm not a dude. Happy to help :))

Comment: Oddly when I try to implement your solution I get the following error message "error  Unexpected require()  global-require". Then I realized it was because my linter (ESLint)  wasn't allowing me to use a require. Just mentioning this in case any one else has this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your v-for. Try to change it to this :

```
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item v-for="item in items">
     <v-img contain :src="item"></v-img>
  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

As your items array only contains urls, you can loop through each item to use the value.

If it doesn't solve your problem, maybe your local url's aren't corrects and you have to verify your project tree to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my project. Try importing local files like this:

```
<script>
    var file1 = require('yourpath')
    var file2 = require('yourpath')

    export default {
    data() {
        items: [
            file1,
            file2,
            "onlineimage",
            "onlineimage"
          ]
      }
    }
</script>
```

This solved my problem. If it still doesn't work, check the path, you might need "./" or "@/" instead of "../".

Also, use array length for your v-for instead of a fixed number. Like this:

```
<v-carousel-item v-for="item in items" :src="item">
</v-carousel-item>
```

Or like this:

```
<v-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :src="item">
</v-carousel-item>
```

Result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in my case it is showing error :                                           
    error  in ./src/assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/1.PNG

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: @SoorajKumar Ah yes, now I remember! I had a '.JPG' file, in uppercase, and got the same error. Changing file format to '.jpg', in lowercase, worked for me. I suggest using a program to change it though (I used GIMP), cause I once tried to force change it in Windows and Vue apparently didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel, vuetify and this worked for me:

"vuetify": "^1.5.1",

webpack.mix.js

```
mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .copyDirectory('resources/assets/img', 'public/img')
```

welcome.vue

```
 <template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" v-bind:src="item.src" :key="i"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'welcome-view',
  layout: 'default',

  metaInfo () {
    return { title: this.$t('home') }
  },
  data () {
   return {
     items: [
       {
         src: '/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/2.PNG'
       },
       {
         src: '/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/1.PNG'
       },
       {
         src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg'
       },
       {
         src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg'
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

where resources/assets/img/PreviousYear/17/top10/2.PNG